# Autofac: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException

Tags: c#, autofac

The server runs but when I try to connect to the server I recieve this Exception:

```
2023-01-12 15:10:00,023 [12] ERROR Photon.SocketServer.Peers.ManagedPeer - Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 
An exception was thrown while activating NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Client.PhotonClientPeer -> 
NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Messaging.ClientHandlerList -> 
Î»:NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Messaging.IHandler`1[[NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Client.IClientPeer, NinjaBricks.Framework, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]][] -> NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Handler.ClientRequestForwardHandler. 
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Handler.ClientRequestForwardHandler' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Support.IClientCodeRemover clientCodeRemover' of constructor 
'Void .ctor(ExitGames.Logging.ILogger, 
NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Server.IServerConnectionCollection`2
   [NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Config.IServerType,
   NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Server.IServerPeer], 
NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Support.IClientCodeRemover, 
NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Config.IServerType)'.
   en Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(ConstructorInfo[] availableConstructors, IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   en Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   en Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepciÃ³n interna ---
   en Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   en Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   en Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   en Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   en lambda_method(Closure , InitRequest )
   en NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.PhotonPeerFactory.CreatePeer[T](IPeerConfig config) en D:\Users\pndia\Documents\GitHub\NinjaBricks\ninja-bricks-game-server\NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton\Implementation\PhotonPeerFactory.cs:lÃ­nea 61
   en Photon.SocketServer.Peers.ManagedPeer.CreatePeerBase(InitRequest initRequest)
```

The code was made by other programmer and It is old code, but I Can't run it properly and i have no documentation about the code.

This is the ClientRequestForwardHandler class:

```
using ExitGames.Logging;
using NinjaBricks.Common;
using NinjaBricks.Common.Codes;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Config;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Messaging;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Client;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Config;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Messaging;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Server;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Support;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Handler
{
    public class ClientRequestForwardHandler : IHandler<IClientPeer>, IDefaultRequestHandler<IClientPeer>
    {
        private readonly IServerConnectionCollection<IServerType, IServerPeer> _serverConnectionCollection;
        private readonly IClientCodeRemover _clientCodeRemover;
        private readonly IServerType _serverType;

        public ILogger Log { get; set; }
        public byte Code { get => 0x0ff; }
        public int? SubCode { get => null; }
        public MessageType Type { get => MessageType.Request; }

        public ClientRequestForwardHandler(ILogger log,
            IServerConnectionCollection<IServerType, IServerPeer> serverConnectionCollection,
            IClientCodeRemover clientCodeRemover,
            IServerType serverType)
        {
            Log = log;
            _serverConnectionCollection = serverConnectionCollection;
            _clientCodeRemover = clientCodeRemover;
            _serverType = serverType;
        }

        public bool HandleMessage(IMessage message, IClientPeer clientPeer)
        {
            if (!message.Parameters.ContainsKey((byte)ParameterCode.ServerType))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var serverType = _serverType.GetServerType(Convert.ToInt32(message.Parameters[(byte)ParameterCode.ServerType]));
            var server = _serverConnectionCollection.GetServersByType<IServerPeer>(serverType).FirstOrDefault();

            if (server != null)
            {
                _clientCodeRemover.RemoveServerType(message);
                _clientCodeRemover.RemovePeerId(message);
                AddMessageCodes(message, clientPeer);
                server.SendMessage(message);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void AddMessageCodes(IMessage message, IClientPeer clientPeer)
        {
            message.Parameters.Add((byte)ParameterCode.PeerId, clientPeer.PeerId.ToByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the IClientCodeRemover:

```
using NinjaBricks.Common.Codes;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Messaging;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Interfaces.Support;

namespace NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Support
{
    public class ClientCodeRemover : IClientCodeRemover
    {
        public void RemovePeerId(IMessage message)
        {
            message.Parameters.Remove((byte)MessageParameterCode.PeerId);
        }

        public void RemoveServerType(IMessage message)
        {
            message.Parameters.Remove((byte)ParameterCode.ServerType);
        }

        public void RemoveName(IMessage message)
        {
            message.Parameters.Remove((byte)ParameterCode.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Also here the configs of autofac:

```
using Autofac;
using NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation;
using NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Client;
using NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Data;
using NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Handler;
using NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Implementation.Server;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Client;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Config;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Messaging;
using NinjaBricks.Framework.Implementation.Server;

namespace NinjaBricks.NinjaPhoton.Modules
{
    public class ProxyServerModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);
            builder.RegisterType<ServerApplication>().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<PhotonPeerFactory>().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<PeerConfig>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

            builder.RegisterType<SubServerClientPeer>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<PhotonClientPeer>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<PhotonServerPeer>().AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            
            builder.RegisterType<ServerConnectionCollection>().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<ClientConnectionCollection>().AsImplementedInterfaces().SingleInstance();
            
            builder.RegisterType<ServerHandlerList>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<EventForwardHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<RequestForwardHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<ResponseForwardHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

            builder.RegisterType<ClientHandlerList>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<ClientRequestForwardHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

            builder.RegisterType<ServerRegistrationHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterType<ServerData>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
    }
}
```

Autofac version 5.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided code it seems that you have forgot to register `ClientCodeRemover`. Try adding:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<ClientCodeRemover>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

To your `ProxyServerModule.Load` method.

Comment: @PatricioDíaz was glad to help! If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of it)